# Going back to previous View Controller and Updating its data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view which stores some data say number of files. On clicking on the view it directs to some other view which stores detailed information about that data say the detailed information about all the files . Now after doing some operations on the second view say deleting some files when I pop the second view controller via this command

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I want the data on the previous view controller to be reloaded automatically say to store the exact number of files. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

1. If you want to send data to the previous viewController and reload, use a delegate.
2. If you want to reload previous viewController without sending any data from the current view controller, just implement reloading methods in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `viewWillAppear` In the first view controller to gather and redisplay the current state of the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways to do this and below is the list sorted according to my preference for this type of implementation :

1. **User Custom Protocols**
   Below is a great reference which demonstrates that how the protocols can be used to implement your scenario.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_protocols.htm

2. If you are using a data source to display the information in first view controller then your should implement `viewWillAppear` to show the file details. This method is called when your view controller is going to be shown on the screen. So whenever you are updating the data source(database or the models) in the second view controller and navigate back to the first view then you will get updated details in the view.
3. Use `NSNotificationCenter`. This is a method which notifies the observer view controllers on a specific event at another place. This should be used when multiple events has to occur on a particular trigger. Below is a great reference to understand this :

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/broadcasting-with-nsnotification-center-8bc0ccd2f5c3

Hope this helps you.